# Saving arrays as columns with np.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do something that is probable very simple. I  would like to save three arrays to a file as columns using 'np.savetxt' When I try this

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
z = [9,10,11,12]

np.savetxt('myfile.txt', (x,y,z), fmt='%.18g', delimiter=' ', newline=os.linesep)
```

The arrays are saved like this

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

But what I wold like is this

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [`numpy.c_[]`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
np.savetxt('myfile.txt', np.c_[x,y,z])
```

Answer (score 50):

Use `numpy.transpose()`:

```
np.savetxt('myfile.txt', np.transpose([x,y,z]))
```

I find this more intuitive than using `np.c_[]`.

Answer (score 19):

I find `numpy.column_stack()` most intuitive:

```
np.savetxt('myfile.txt', np.column_stack([x,y,z]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use zip:

`np.savetxt('myfile2.txt', zip(x,y,z), fmt='%.18g')`

For python3 list+zip:

`np.savetxt('myfile.txt', list(zip(x,y,z)), fmt='%.18g')`

To understand the workaround see here: [How can I get the "old" zip() in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090117/how-can-i-get-the-old-zip-in-python3) and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5951.

Answer (score 0):

I find the one with **delimiter** as most intuitive:

```
np.savetxt('myfile.txt', np.c_[x,y,z], delimiter = ',')
```