# How can I get the "old" zip() in Python3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I migrated from Python 2.7 to Python 3.3 and zip() does not work as expected anymore.
Indeed, I read in the doc that it now returns an iterator instead of a list.

So, how I am supposed to deal with this? Can I use the "old" zip() in my Python3 code?

Find bellow the way it worked before in a Django project:

in views.py: `my_zipped_list = zip(list1, list2)`

in file.html: `{{ my_zipped_list.0.1 }}`

Maybe another solution would be to keep "new" zip() behaviour and change template instead.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It's usually better to write your code so it doesn't care whether it's got an iterator or a list or anything else, as long as it's iterable. Sometimes that isn't possible, in which case you have to pass whatever iterable you get to the `list` function (or `iter`, or `tuple`, or whatever's appropriate for what you're trying to do). But first, try to look at whether you actually need to.

Comment: The conversion of zip() from returning a list to returning an iterator can result in a silent bug in formerly working code. The bug occurs when code a) creates a zip; b) iterates over the returned value; c) iterates over the returned value again. When zip() returned a list, both (b) and (c) would iterate over the zipped list. When zip() just returns an iterator, (b) iterates over the results, but (c) silently does nothing. I don't think 2to3 catches this either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make a list of the result by doing `list(zip(...))`.

Comment: And keep this solution in mind because you'll need it often when iterators get in your way (e.g., with `dict.keys()` etc.)

Comment: @alexis: `dict.keys()` isn't an iterator, it's a view (the same as `dict.viewkeys()` in 2.x, not the same as `dict.iterkeys()`).

Comment: Right, that was sloppy of me to say; but it's all the same when you expect a list you don't understand why you can't index it, or whatever.