# numpy.savetxt: Write 1D array into multiple rows and colums

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I have a 1D numpy array like

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Which I want to write into a .txt file in multiple rows and columns, and various spaces in between, like:

```
HEADER
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
 7   8
```

The number of columns should be specified, the number of rows adjusted.

Is there an easy way to do this using numpy.savetxt or something similar?

Comment: might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192847/saving-arrays-as-columns-with-np-savetxt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_split` :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

with open('out_file.txt','w') as f :
     for i in np.array_split(a,3) :
         f.write('  '.join(map(str,i)))
```

result :

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I want to specify the number of columns, not the number of rows. (I just added that to the description.)